# NameError in function, nested in __init__ method

Tags: python, oop

```
class sheet:
    def __init__(self):
        def close_game():
            print("game closed")
        def click():
            eval("close_game()")

        click()

s1 = sheet()
```

I'm getting such error:

```
  File "<string>", line 6, in click
NameError: name 'close_game' is not defined
```

But if I replace 'eval("close_game()")' with 'close_game()' it works correctly. Please explain to me why it works like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval` does not have access to the scope chain. It can only see immediate local variables by default:

```
def outer():
    non_loc = 1

    def inner_var():
        print(non_loc)

    def inner_eval():
        print(eval('non_loc'))

    inner_var()   # ok
    inner_eval()  # not ok


outer()
```

You can, however, pass whatever you want in the `locals` argument.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) sets up its own namespace and `close_game` is not present in that namespace by default. You can add it explicitly like this:

```py
...
        def close_game():
            print("game closed")
        def click():
            eval("close_game()", {"close_game": close_game})
```

Then it will resolve properly and the function will be called as expected.

**PS:** I suppose it is prudent to mention that using `eval` is usually risky business. Just in case you are not aware, it is easy to introduce huge security vulnerabilities. This has been discussed on this platform extensively, so I am just going to leave this warning.